# Azure Synapse SQL managed endpoint terraform error

Tags: terraform, pool, azure-synapse

I'm trying to deploy a synapse workspace with a dedicated SQL pool. It creates the resources, but errors when trying to created a managed endpoint stating the resource id is not in the right format. I have the data lake managed endpoint deployed successfully.

```
resource "azurerm_synapse_managed_private_endpoint "sql_mpe" {
    name = "dedicated-sql-mpe"
    synapse_workspace_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.synapse.id
    target_resource_id = azurerm_synapse_sql_pool.sql_pool.id
    subresource_name = "sql"
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a dedicated SQL pool the Managed Private Endpoint and Link Service are automatically created now and a standard private endpoint is not supported.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).